# Guardar los artículos correctamente del carrito de compras en tabla

Tags: php, laravel

espero puedan ayudarme soy nuevo en el desarrollo, ahora esto realizando un carrito de compras usando laravel 7, mi problema que tengo el siguiente:
dentro de la cesta de mi carrito de compras contiene los artículos agregados, tengo un formulario donde obtengo los datos del carrito pero al guardarlos me inserta el ultimo articulo duplicando la cantidad de productos que tengo en la cesta del carrito ( ejemplo tengo 3 artículos, ultimo articulo se inserta 3 veces), tengo relacion con otro modelo donde almaceno el total de venta espero puedan ayudarme de ante mano gracias...

método store de mi controlador

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->except(['btnAccion','_token']); 
    $carrito = session('carrito', [] );
        
    $sales = $this->ticketRepository->create($input);
 
    foreach ( $carrito as $producto ){
    $sales = $this->ticketLineRepository->create($input);
    }

    return redirect('sales')->with('sales', $sales);

}
```

formulario de vista

```
<form action="{{ Route('sales.store') }}" method="post">
 @foreach($carrito as $producto)

 div class="form-group col-sm-6">
 {!! Form::label('product_id', 'Product') !!}
 {!! Form::text('product_id',$producto['id'], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Product']) !!};
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6" style="">
 {!! Form::label('quantity', 'Quantity:') !!}
 {!! Form::number('quantity', $producto['cantidad'],null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Quantity']) !!}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6" style="">
 {!! Form::label('unit_price', 'Unit Price:') !!}
 {!! Form::number('unit_price', $producto['precio'], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Unit Price']) !!}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6" style="">
 {!! Form::label('total', 'Total:') !!}
 {!! Form::number('total', (int)$producto['precio'] * (int)$producto['cantidad'] ,null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Total']) !!}
 </div>
 @endforeach
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
 {!! Form::label('tracking_number', 'Tracking Number:') !!}
 {!! Form::text('tracking_number', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Tracking Number']) !!}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
 {!! Form::label('type', 'Type:') !!}
 {!! Form::text('type', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Type']) !!}
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" name="btnAccion" value="pagar" type="submit" > Pagar </button>
</form>
```

modelo 1

```
    class ticket_line extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;
        public $table = 'ticket_lines';  
        const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
        const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
        public $fillable = [
            'ticket_id',
            'product_id',
            'quantity',
            'unit_price',
            'total',
            'tracking_number',
            'type'
        ];
}
public function ticket()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\ticket::class, 'ticket_id');
}
```

modelo 2

```
class ticket extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    public $table = 'tickets';
    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public $fillable = [
     'total'
    ];
 }
public function ticketLines()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\TicketLine::class, 'ticket_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola no soy muy experimentado tampoco en Laravel pero me parece que el problema esta en tu foreach al utilizar create, si vas a guardar un conjunto de productos mejor usa el método de new `nombre de tu modelo`.
Suponiendo que tu modelo se llama ticketRepository entonces seria algo asi

```
foreach ( $carrito as $producto ){

$sales = new ticketLineRepository;
$salea->'aqui vas poniendo los atributos de tu modelo' = $input['aqui va el valor de la propiedad name de tus etiquetas en el formulario'];
}
```